# When is the complex conjugate group representation not equivalent to the original?

Tags: group-theory, vector-spaces, representation-theory

I am reading *Representation Theory of Finite Groups* by Benjamin Steinberg. In Example 3.6, it is stated:

> Let $\varphi:G\to GL_n(\mathbb{C})$ be a representation. Show that setting $\psi_g=\overline{\varphi_g}$ provides a representation $G\to GL_n(\mathbb{C})$. ... Give an example showing $\varphi$ and $\psi$ do not have to be equivalent.

I'm sort of stumped here. I don't have a concrete example of two representations that are not equivalent, but I also can't immediately think of a $\mathbb{C}$-(vector space) automorphism $T$ such that conjugating by $T$ gives the complex conjugate. I suppose my question is: can someone please provide a non-trivial example of when the complex conjugate is an equivalent representation, and one where it isn't? Any explanations of how to view this in general would also be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just looking at one-dimensional representations of $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$, the trivial representation is self-conjugate, and the other two are conjugates.

Comment: @Joppy can you give me a non-trivial example?

Comment: As @Joppy says, the irreducible representations of $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ are characterized by their value $\phi^k([1]) = \exp(2\pi k/3)$ on the generator $[1]$ of $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$, where $k=0,1,2$. The $k=1,2$ representations are conjugate, and not equivalent. If this doesn't count as a non-trivial example, perhaps you need to explain what you're looking for.

Comment: Sure - take the Dihedral group corresponding to a triangle. There are trivial and sign one-dimensional representations which are self-conjugate. The other two representations are both two-dimensional and conjugate to each other.

Comment: @user17945 sorry, I didn't understand the comment at first, but I understand now. Thanks everyone! Can someone write an answer so I can verify it? I just don't want this question to remain in unanswered limbo forever lol